# Convert Data Set Object .text to Int32 Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I am using a database with my Visual Basic application, and arranged code for a simple add and display procedure (see below).

The fields are shown as text boxes with the DataType properties set as Int32, and DateTime as UnspecifiedLocal by default.

I am repeatedly getting an error and it insists I am trying to convert DateTime.

> input string is not in the correct format

I have tried changing the DataType to String and removing the `convert.toint32` but it still gives me the same error.

I would greatly appreciate your help on how to resolve this error message and fix my simple little procedure!

```
Private Sub StrTol()
    Dim intBase As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Base_Score1TextBox.Text)
    Dim intRace As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Base_Race_Mod1TextBox.Text)
    Dim intEnh As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Enh_Bonus1TextBox.Text)
    Dim intMisc As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Mis1TextBox.Text)
    Dim intSum As Integer

    If intBase > 0 Then
    ElseIf intRace > 0 Then
    ElseIf intEnh > 0 Then
    ElseIf intMisc > 0 Then
        intSum = intBase + intRace + intEnh + intMisc
        txtStr.Text = intSum
    Else
        MsgBox("Input Error", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error")

    End If
```

Comment: I apologize, the DataType is set to System.String which is why I was  using the Convert.ToInt32 THEN doing the math. So I changed the DataType to System.Int32 and removed the conversion and left only the TextBox.text to assign value. I should also state that the input string error reference DateTime happens even when valid numeric is in the text boxes and when they are empty, even though if they are empty it should bounce the message box.

Comment: Your question is very confusing.  FIrst you dont tell us where the error happens; the titel talks about a DataSet object but there is no DS in your code; then you talk about DateTime and there is nothing to do with DateTime either.

Comment: The code provided is where the error happens. Right there at the second line with the assignment of intBase. intBase is a variable that pulls from the data bound text box and text property of that text box, which is item Base_Score1TextBox. So I pulled a DataSet field over to the app form as a textbox for the user to enter input, and now that variable wants the contents of that box. No, there is not DateTime. That is the point. No where in my code or object properties do I set or use DateTime.

Comment: So in summary, the question is: How do I fix the error of Input string is not in the correct format with code details about trying to convert DateTime? I am not using any form of DateTime and that variable should be able to pull the contents of a data bound textbox with DataType int32.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by: Removing entirely the If-Then and placing from " Dim intBase = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox.Text)" down to "txtStr,text = intsum" into a Try-Catch block with FormatException as the catching exception and placing the MsgBox result beneath the Catch Excpetion before End Try.

Code:

```
Private Sub StrVal()
    'Validate user entry
    Try
        Dim intBase As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Base_Score1TextBox.Text)
        Dim intRace As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Base_Race_Mod1TextBox.Text)
        Dim intEnh As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Enh_Bonus1TextBox.Text)
        Dim intMisc As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Mis1TextBox.Text)
        intSum = intBase + intRace + intEnh + intMisc
        txtStr.Text = intSum
    Catch Exceptoin As FormatException
        MsgBox("Input Error", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error")
    End Try
```